# Trying to make function subtract a defined number by one error "missing 1 required positional argument"

Tags: python

I'm just learning python and after a month of no practice I cannot figure this out. How do I increment the "order" by -1 without causing error. TypeError: increment_one() missing 1 required positional argument: 'one'

```
class Restaurant():

    def __init__(self, restaurant_name, cuisine_type):
        self.restaurant_name=restaurant_name
        self.cuisine_type=cuisine_type
        self.number_serv=0

    def desc_restaurant(self):
        print("The restaurant name is:"+self.restaurant_name+" The 
        restaurant type is:"+self.cuisine_type)
    def open_restaurant(self):
        print(self.restaurant_name+"is now open")

    def number_served(self):
        """Print a statement showing the car's mileage."""
        print("Number of orders to serve: " + str(self.number_serv))
    def increment_serv(self,number):
        self.number_serv=number
       def increment_one(self,one):
        one=number-1

  mcdz = Restaurant('Mcdonald', 'Burger')
  mcdz.desc_restaurant()
  mcdz.open_restaurant()
  mcdz.increment_serv(34)
  mcdz.number_served()
  mcdz.increment_one()
```

Comment: Your indentation is inconsistent, it matters in python. Can you fix this first and see if your error goes away

Comment: It says it's missing a parameter because it is. Your function is defined as `increment_one(self,one)`. `one` is a parameter (which you use wrongly, but that's another story) that the function expects to be given when it's called. If you just call `increment_one()` you get the error you're getting. Also, as a side note, `increment_one` does not modify the state of your object (it doesn't use `self`) and it doesn't return anything, so it's effectively doing nothing at the moment.

Answer (score 2):

Your code defines `increment_one` as follows:

```
def increment_one(self,one):
    one=number-1
```

and calls it as follows:

```
mcdz.increment_one()
```

The error message is because your own definition of the method calls for a parameter that the calling code is not supplying. Do it this way:

```
def increment_one(self):
    self.number -= 1
```

(though I would call that method `decrement` not `increment`).

Answer (score 0):

Your `increment_one` function takes two arguments, `self` and `one`. You are only passing `self` to it. Change this line:

```
mcdz.increment_one()
```

to pass an additional value within the parentheses, or change this line:

```
def increment_one(self,one):
```

to this:

```
def increment_one(self):
```

if you don't want to pass any parameters.

Additionally, within `increment_one`, you did not define the `number` variable. You must define that for it to work.